# Flutter Web gradient text on Safari

Tags: flutter

I have an issue with Flutter Web on Safari. My website crashes as soon as Gradient Text is displayed. Does anyone have a way to fix it?

My code here:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class GradientText extends StatelessWidget {
  const GradientText({
    super.key,
    required this.text,
    this.gradient = const LinearGradient(colors: _colors),
    this.style,
  });

  static const _colors = [Color(0xFFF496D3), Color(0xFFF4AB61)];

  final String text;
  final TextStyle? style;
  final Gradient gradient;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ShaderMask(
      blendMode: BlendMode.srcIn,
      shaderCallback: (bounds) => gradient.createShader(
        Rect.fromLTWH(0, 0, bounds.width, bounds.height),
      ),
      child: Text(text, style: style),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: are you getting any errors/logs in console for it?